# openpyxl seems to be breaking files that have powerQuery in them

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need to take the weeknumber from the filename and use that to print a date in Cell M5 on the Sheet "input"

this code will work perfect with an Excel file that do not have Power Query in it.
how ever as soon as there are Power Query, it will corrupt the file and i need to Repair it (loosing all my Power Querys)

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar
import openpyxl

folder_path = "c:/icons/ugelistchangedate/"
week_numbers = [11, 12, 13, 15]
sheet_name = "Input"
cell_location = "M5"

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
        for week_number in week_numbers:
            if f"{week_number}" in filename.lower():
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

                # Calculate last date of week number
                year = datetime.now().year
                week_start = datetime.strptime(f"{year}-W{week_number}-1", "%G-W%V-%u")
                week_end = datetime.strptime(f"{year}-W{week_number}-7", "%G-W%V-%u")

                if week_start.month == week_end.month:
                    # Last date of the given week number
                    last_date_of_week = week_end.date()
                else:
                    # Last date of the month
                    last_date_of_week = datetime(year=year, month=week_start.month, day=calendar.monthrange(year, week_start.month)[1]).date()

                # Open the workbook and write the date in the specified sheet and cell
                workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path, read_only=False, keep_vba=True, keep_links=True, data_only=True)
                sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
                sheet[cell_location].value = last_date_of_week.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                workbook.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Power Query is some kind of commerical plugin, I guess. Openpyxl only supports the OOXML file specification.

Comment: Power Q is Microsoft Standard - for getting data info Excel , and had been for many years. 
No 3. Party involved.

Comment: That might be the case, but it's not part of Excel itself and not covered by the OOXML specification.